# Libre Office (or Open Office) create a Writer template with image background

Tags: openoffice, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am seeking a Writer-type application that will allow me to set an image page background (for stationery papers) and save it as a template.

I have Libre Office right now and I choose Format->Page->Background->Graphics. The image loads, but the way it is displayed on the page is wrong. I want it to appear in the top left corner ***outside*** of the writing area. So that it starts literally from the left top paper edge and the writing area is more inside. But in reality, the background image appears ***inside*** the writing area and I can't find a way to fix it.

How to make Libre Office Writer (or any other free writer application based on Open Office, like Lotus Symphony or other) to place the page background image ***outside*** of writing area in Writer??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the easiest way to have an image on all pages is to put in the header.

- To do this first go to **Format > Page**, select the *Header* tab and check the *Header on* box.
- Then click into the header and go to **Insert > Picture > From File...** and select your image.
- At this point the image will appear on all pages but not not as a background. Click the image (you might have to click it inside the header section) and go to **Format > Wrap > In Background**. Now your text appears before your image.
- You can now drag it around and scale it at the edges to make it fit the page.

Comment: Yeah... this is a nice workaround. In case the background picture takes more or less the whole page, this step must be applied as last step after finishing edits, because inserting a big picture disables mouse selection of paragraph on page (even if picture is added to header and in background). An option is missing to just block the picture, make it unsellectable. But anyway, it's a good workaround, I needed this solution really, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Thanks a lot for this very useful tip!

If you loose your picture "behind" the main text area. I mean after dragging the picture out of the header or footer area, it may be difficult for you to select it again. You can solve this by calling the navigator (F5) box. Under "images" you would be able to go through the list and double click and select you background picture.